# What do we call people who go to the gym?

Tags: single-word-requests

A group of people who regularly attend gym classes or work-out. What are they called? Is there a single-word for this particular group?

Apart from my calling them *fanatics*, *mad* (BrEng)/*crazy* (AmEng), *body-obsessed*, *vain* or *dull*.

Seriously, what are they? 
[***Devotees***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devotee)? [***Learners***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/learner)? [***Practitioners***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practitioner)?

I'd also appreciate any equivalent popular/recognized expressions that haven't yet entered any standard dictionary but have been *buzzing* around for a few years.

***Trivia***
In Italian, a gym is called *palestra*. Italians are very body conscious and tend to look after themselves very well, in fact it is true to say that it's quite difficult to find overweight, unattractive, or unfit men or women who attend these almost daily sessions. The men, in particular, can get carried away and so the expression *palestrato* has been coined in the Italian language. A [**palestrato**](https://www.google.it/search?q=palestrato&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=I9EhUpPdFMTpswbh04CAAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1366&bih=613) is someone who **frequently attends the gym**, but is also an exhibitionist, self-obsessed, extremely vain, and very very muscular.

Comment: Google returns 137000 results for *Workoutaholic*.

Comment: It depends. If it's January, and the workout clothes are new, you could call them [resolutioners](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Resolutioner) :^)

Comment: Are you looking for a word for anyone who does this activity by a defining characteristic (eg someone who acts is called an 'actor') or for a slang or slightly derogatory term that has these extra characteristics? That is, do you want a word for someone who goes to the gym or do you want the English translation of 'Palestrato'?

Comment: I found a [fitness center in Italy named “Gymmy”](http://www.gymmy.it/). I kind of like that as a general adjective, maybe as a noun. *Rob is quite a gymmy guy. Feeling gymmy this morning? This place is filled with gymmies, isn’t it?*

Comment: @Mitch  I want a term that describes people who frequently go to the gym. I had searched previously and didn't find any, hence my asking if any colloquial expression or slang term already exists. I added the "palestrato" trivia to illustrate that in Italian the phenomenon of body-fitness, and (fanatical) gym-goers (for want of a better word) has indeed created a new word. I'm not asking for the exact translation of *palestrato*, because, as far as I know, there isn't one. To sum up, men and women, who regularly go to the gym; is there a word or common expression?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I'm unfamiliar with Italian: Is *palestra* -> *palestrato* a standard Italian construction, or is it a pun on *castrato*?

Comment: @NateEldredge It's purely coincidental. There are hundreds of words that end in "[ato](http://trovaparole.com/ends-with-by-length/ato/)" in Italian.

Comment: Well no offense, but Italians eat a lot of pasta and this is not  body conscious.

Comment: @speedyGonzales  Come and visit Milan, Turin, Venice, Bologna, Parma etc. Obesity is not as widespread as it is in the UK or in the US. I can assure you that women clothes beyond size 52 is very rare. Most trendy boutiques stock up to size 46 (generally a UK size 16). Italian men (overall) are also very body conscious, I don't see many pot-bellies where I live.

Comment: Venice, Florence, Roma, Vatican checked- I was on 10 days trip when I was in 11th grade. I remember that I had to take shower bending my knees(I am 5' 11") and there was pasta for breakfast, lunch and dinner. I was impressed that there are so narrow streets in Rome and from the number of scooters. btw here it is modern to be buff and there are a lot of buff boys, which I find really stupid to gamble with your health and taking supplements so when I was in Italy I found most Italians a little bit on the thick side. There are parts of Bulgaria with fat people maybe, but not where I live in.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A term that I have heard, that seems to be widely accepted, and that I would use myself, is simply "gym goer". I don't think you'll find anything better than that, if you want a generic and neutral term. Google has [704,000 hits for it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=gym%20goer&btnG=S%C3%B6k)

*(I'm not a native English speaker, but I have been to the gym twice this week and plan on a third time, and I frequent web sites about strength training.)*

Comment: I thought I was making it up myself, but I've checked. It does exist.

Answer (score 58):

I'm afraid I can only provide two words: *gym rat*.

Comment: Well, to me it's certainly a new expression! Thank you. Is it very common in the UK?

Comment: I've also heard _gym bunny,_ akin to _snow bunny._

Comment: Not sure it's common, but the fact that I've heard of it must mean something.

Comment: A gym bunny is slightly different, though: it is specifically someone who works out and goes to the gym a lot _just_ in order to look ripped for the clubs. It's a derogatory term implying vanity and shallowness—and it's almost always, in my experience, applied to gay men.

Comment: (An even more specific term, denoting gay men who are gym bunnies, but pump themselves up to compensate for being otherwise quite effeminate, is _Muscle Mary_. That one is even more derogative.)

Comment: To me, a "gym rat" is a person who goes to the gym often and has been doing so for a long time. I think what is requested here is a more general term?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree that *Muscle Mary* is a gay term, but I had no idea that *gym bunny* was! Now I worry that I may have something wildly inappropriate. :)

Comment: I should perhaps rather have said that I’ve almost always heard it used for gay men _and women_. There’s a certain aspect of femininity in the ‘bunny’ part of the term that I think lends itself to being used mostly for (perceivedly feminine) gay guys, and of course women.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Agreed, thus the connection to _snow bunny,_ which has similar connotations. From Urban Dictionary: “a girl that goes to the mountains to wear cute ski/snowboard clothes to drink hot chocolate and hit on the hot ski lift boys. usually not very good at skiing/snowboarding.” (Apparently _snow bunny_ means a few other things too that I was not aware of.)

Comment: In my experience, "gym rat" carries a connotation of hanging around all day in the gym. "Rat" is used in a manner similar to "bum", meaning someone who engages in a leisure activity all day, like a "skate rat".

Comment: Gun Bunny is also a common term to describe girls who A) like to be around guys who have/shoot guns or B) are themselves gun enthusiasts.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say, @JanusBahsJacquet, except I don't think it's necessarily derogatory. It does imply a certain vanity, or at least a desire to be desired, and it is mainly applied to (and by?) gay men. But none of those things is necessarily (or often?) an insult?

Answer (score 21):

From my humble non native speaker point of view, most of the expressions suggested above (gym-nerd, gym dandy, gym rat, ...) sound pretty negative, if not insulting.

If one used one of these with me, I would probably put him in my black list.

In martial arts, which I practiced for several years, we used normally the equivalent of the term "practitioners" (martial arts are often intended also as ways of life).

If one has to make up expressions, why not to be more positive and ecouraging: not everybody is a "library rat" or a "library nerd" :-)), and some moderate exercise is certainly good for health.

So I'd propose also: "gym enthusiast", "fitness enthusiast", "practitioner" (depending on the context).

EDIT.
I have seen you have added also "palestrato". This is suggesting that you are possibly looking for a more negative connotations, and probably in the area of body building.

In this area, I can suggest these:

buff, 
pumped, ripped

the native speakers maybe can explain the differences. "buff" should be much more positive than the Italian "palestrato", and "ripped" or "sculpted" definitely desirable.

The perfect living caricature of a "palestrato" is this guy (Davide di Porto):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im7mbBxw7aU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6WN4ghnX6A

In this case the ("romanaccio") word "Appalestrato" is used, which is a lot funny and self-ironic. The "A" suggesting, I guess, a sort of addiction, but also a typical Roman inflexion ("Aho", "Allo?").

(It's actually hard to describe how funny these videos are.)

Comment: ‘Gym rat’ _can_ be derogatory, but it is often neutral or even admiratory. It is mostly used in a derogatory manner by people who would also make it clear that they are using ‘fitness enthusiast’ in a derogatory manner; i.e., people who look down on the concept of going to the gym in the first place.

Comment: _Gym rat_ was the first thing that popped into my mind, and, insofar as I know, it's not generally considered derogatory (although just about _anything_ can be uttered in a contemptuous or insulting way). Still, if you don't like _gym rat_, ["fitness buffs"](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22fitness+buffs%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) got a lot of Google hits, and they seemed complimentary.

Comment: As an Italian (and with nerdy shape ) I would point that 'palestrato' has not necessarily a negative connotation.

Answer (score 16):

**Muscle Head** & **Fitness Freak** may apply too.

Comment: I have heard "fitness freak" used a lot.

Comment: Muscle head definitely applies. Meaty lifter types.

Answer (score 12):

Gym probably derives from gymnasium.  Maybe gymnast is technically correct, but wrong based on accepted usage.

Part of the difficulty is that Gym is not one thing. There are lifters, walkers, joggers, runners, yogis all in one place with different objectives, slimmers, bodybuilders and so on.  There are professionals, amateurs, athletes, and bored housewives.

I have heard people saying 'gymming' to mean that they are going to the gym, as in 'I am gymming from 6 to 8'.  Maybe it is time to coin 'gymmers'?

Comment: ‘Gymmers’ sounds more like a type of clothes to me, like ‘jammies’ and ‘sneakers’ mixed into one. Perhaps a new gymming outfit to be patented?

Comment: Perhaps it is time to coin a new expression, but I'm interested in hearing about those that already exist as I no longer live in the UK and I'm afraid of losing touch! :)

Comment: I gave this a +1, because we really do apply a label based on what activities they pursue at the gym. I knew a guy that went to the gym daily to swim, so he was a swimmer. The guys who go to to lift weights are called weight-lifters, or as a current trend "jacked"...

Comment: @AthomSfere your comment makes a lot of sense, and I admit I like BinaryNights contribution, the *ing* verbal form, gymming.

Comment: The other problem with the word "gymmer", at least in the United States, is that when spoken aloud, it sounds a lot like the first name of [Jimmer Fredette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmer_Fredette), a fairly popular major-league basketball player. The word would likely end up meaning that a person is skilled at long-distance shots in basketball, not that they go to the gym.

Answer (score 7):

In my younger days such a person was usually referred to as a *fitty* or a *fit-boy*. I can't run down a reference for this, though; the nearest I have found is [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fitty):-

> 1 dial chiefly Eng : suitable and becoming : appropriate
>
> 2 dial
> chiefly Eng (a) : being in good order : trim (b) : handsome, striking

(meaning 2a).

Comment: The website doesn't allow me to read the link, but it does sound typically British.

Comment: A boy can be fit just by playing football (or other sports) all day...

Answer (score 3):

He is a [gym-nerd](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gym%20nerd). Still not exactly one word, but might work in your case.

Comment: -1. -1. -1. -1.

Comment: Are you -1’ing yourself?!

Comment: Despite this being someone (male or female) who tends to be over-zealous. I've not heard of it, and it exists so, +1 from me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, someone else did it, which made me super excited and pressed on the down arrow key several times, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't pertain specifically to going to the gym as distinct from, say, running or jogging a lot, but my first thought is **keep-fit fanatic**.

(I don't think I've heard any of the other terms suggested, but then, I did my best to avoid the gym at school and have done so ever since!)

Comment: I know that expression well enough and I've used it in the past myself, but it's not exclusive to people who go to the gym. I believe, you can be a *keep-fit fanatic* in the privacy of your home. They include people who buy their own body-building equipment; stationary bikes, treadmills etc. and train at home.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [***megarexia***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Megarexia)

This word is informal, rather playful and tends to be used less in a derogative sense.

A rather less elegant variant is [***bigorexia***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bigorexia)

There is no harm in calling them [***gym-bugs***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bug) non-pejoratively is there? In fact googling ***gymbug***produced a number of fitness centres with that name. And ***fitness bug*** is a commnonly used phrase.

Answer (score 3):

As an active gym enthusiast, I will share with you the two terms we use.

1. She is such a great cyclist! But, she only does spin class, she doesn't ride outdoors. Her boyfriend is a competitive body builder. She has been teaching him how to incorporate more cardiovascular workouts.
2. Even though she cannot train outside because of her injuries, she is an excellent athlete.

We use specifics and we say: Athlete.  Maybe because of the endorphins, we're feeling positive?   Seriously, the definition of athlete is a person who is trained or skilled in exercises, sports, or games requiring physical strength, agility, or stamina.

We also say, Gym Rat.  But only to tease a friend, it can feel rude.  A lot of present and former competitors use the gym.  Reducing a person's accomplishments down really trivializes their life's work. It's similar to a blonde joking with another blonde, but brunettes, please don't tell blonde jokes.

A triathlete at the gym is not a gym rat. 
A retiree at her first yoga class is a newbie.

Comment: I would argue that a triathlete at the gym _can_ be a gym rat – provided that it's not an occasional visit to the gym, but part of a regular routine.

Answer (score 3):

How about fitness-chondriac? I like Gymnaholic too.  Those are titles for people that are crazy addicted to workout facilities and don't do any outdoor exercise at all.  But a person who does both and not obsessively, I would call just plain healthy.  That would mean the rest of their lives follow suit with nutrition and avoiding bad habits as well, however.

Comment: **Gymaholic** (without the "n") a word for people addicted to going to the gym, does exist, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most words in most languages are derivatives of other existing words. That being said, we can start with... JOCK

> Definition of JOCK from Merriam-Webster Dictionary
>
> > 1: athletic supporter
> >
> > **2: athlete; especially : a school or college athlete**
> >
> > 3: pilot; especially : a fighter pilot
> >
> > **4: a person devoted to a single pursuit or interest** (computer jocks)

Now the second definition is a good root for the new word, as gyms are associated strongly with both schools and athletes. Further, the fourth definition only goes to strengthen the choice for the root, as it also applies in the context of the definition for the question posted. So let's take that root and increase it's specificity to isolate the location, and we end up with...

> **Gymjock**

Even if it does sound like a Klingon word, LOL

Comment: I would prefer that people didn't make-up words or create portmanteau words just so they can write an answer. :) I don't think "Gymjocks" will catch on, as the term *jock* sounds pretty obscure. Maybe it's only used in the US?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Words are created every day... Take 'conversate' as an example (which IMO should have never been) to replace 'conversation'. Sometimes a new word needs to be created to obtain the explicit definition desired. All these replies were at one time, or are, 'made-up' words. As a matter of fact, you will not find many of the other words given as answers as being in a dictionary as well. 'Gymjocks' is just as valid an answer as 'gym rat', 'gym goer', 'gym-nerd', 'gym dandy',or 'keep-fit fanatic'... all made up words. I'm only getting knocked because of bias to the sound of the word.

Comment: Yes, words are created every day, and some take off and others do not. Gym rat and keep-fit-fanatic are in the dictionary; gym junkie/goer/nerd/enthusiast/aholic and megarexia, muscle head, and fitness freak all seem to be expressions which have been around for some time. I'm not interested and I didn't ask for users to think of any new alternative expressions. I was curious if a single-word existed, and in any slang terms which have been established. If you can find any references for GymJock, I'd be too happy to give you an up-vote. Fairer than that, I don't know what is.

Comment: "Jock" is actually quite similar to "palestrato", in that a jock is usually someone seen as very self-confident and may use said confidence to be a playboy, or a top, and so on. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jock

Answer (score 3):

How about "[gym attendee](http://sunfedranch.com/commitment/your-family/)" and "[gym buff](http://supplementsinfo.org/what-gym-buffs-must-know-about-protein-powders/)?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA "gym buff" is better than the accepted "goer", as "goer" does not convey the obsession palestrato/a do. Also "buff" can mean physically fit, so it is kind of an accidental—though stillborn—pun in a way.

Comment: @thomas this answer was posted almost eight months after I had asked this question. If it had been posted at the end of August 2013  I might very well have accepted this answer. Please upvote Elian's great suggestion in the meantime, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Very late comment but just read the question.  These suggestions are ridiculous to a native American speaker - absolutely.  Attendee is used for an event.  You don't attend the grocery store you go to it.    Buff is even MORE wrong.  A gym buff would be a person who studies and is a lover of gyms.  A gym buff would tell me their favorite gym architecture and layout (I don't think these people exist but if there where gym buffs this is what they would do).   Holy cow!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a joke, but how about a: **Trainee**.

train·ee  [trey-nee]

noun

1. a person being trained, especially in a vocation; apprentice.
2. an enlisted person undergoing military training.

Comment: This is a correct answer, also used by many fitness authors. However, there is the problem that not everyone who goes to gym *train* (in order to reach a long term goal) - some go merely for *exercise* (for recreational or other purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Gym-junkie if they go way too often e.g. every day, too many hours.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up your question?

Comment: I've checked using Google, and I only saw one reference to Gymbonite and that was a blogger profile, and one, Urban Dictionary, for Gym nazi (two words) Gym-Junkie seems quite established, but -1 for the seemingly "made-up" expressions, unless you can provide some back-up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA : updated the answer. Those are words I have heard and used, the reference for them is if they can be used and understood and taken on by others with little or no explanation. Reference Nazi! I just made up the reference Nazi, but does it need a reference as well? :) Ps: thank you for explaining why down voted.

Comment: retracted down-vote and one up-vote.

Comment: I have seen this word used on a Twitter profile. The user looked Asian, but from San Francisco, so possibly a native speaker.

Comment: @Pam Gym- Are you talking about "Gym-Junkie"? I had never heard this expression, so I checked and it appears to be an established term. I would prefer that people didn't make-up words or create portmanteau words just so they can write an answer. :)

Comment: @Pam : Gym-Junkie is very common in Australia. pretty muxh X-Junkie (where X can be anything like chocolate to Movie) is readily understood. I have used other words as well and they are understood. Another word would Fitness-Fanatic or Fitness-Junkie.

Answer (score 1):

In the **English** language, when a noun does an activity, in usual cases it is shown by, attaching a verb, in this case a *"to-be"* verb. Similarly, A group of people who regularly attend gym classes or work-out, are called; **"Gym Goers"**. **Gym** *(Gymming) - The Act* and **Go** *(Goer) The verb.*

Answer (score 1):

If *gym goer* isn't enough, e.g. because you want to stress that the person is very focused on the gym, often **lifter** can convey the meaning. Sure, as [Kinjal Dixit says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/124686) a gym goer doesn't necessarily lift, but a lifter usually needs a gym of sorts.

For the "pro" kind, **bodybuilder** may be in order.

Then there are the options which don't focus on the means used by the person, in your case the gym, but rather on how the person is/shows.

- If you want to stress the end result i.e. the muscular type, with a positive or negative connotation depending on what one thinks of muscles, you could say *hunk*.
- If you want to stress the social/sexual/psychological aspect, then see the answer on *jock*.

Answer (score 0):

How about callin g him "a gym dandy"?

Comment: I am asking for a group of people, not a man or woman "gym goer".

Comment: -1 I would prefer that people didn't make-up words or create portmanteau words just so they can write an answer. I thought this word existed. Instead it appears to be reserved for real gymnasts, as in those who do gymnastics; or names of girl teams (surprisingly!) or a type of children's [see-saw](http://www.amazon.com/Gym-Dandy-Spinning-Teeter-Totter/dp/B005MZ60RK). I didn't see any references to *people* who go to the gym.

Answer (score 0):

How about: gymnies - not yet a proper word but covers many perceptions

Comment: It sounds rather derogatory and please no more negativity about people who frequent gyms. Its like calling a gynaecologist 'gynie' - not very nice :)

Comment: @user49727 It sounds just fine to me, not at all derogatory. There’s even a workout gym by the name of *Gymmy*, so it’s not entirely new. I grant you that the  *gymny* spelling is a bit odd at first but quite understandable. All in all this seems a nice word for it.

Comment: I checked on Google and it appears to be a popular name for gymns, not for people. It also seems to be used as a diminutive for [**pyjamas**](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/gymboree-boys-pajamas). The one perception I'm interested in, people who attend gym classes, there appears to be no evidence of. So -1 from me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be perfect timing to ask such a question. Recently a gym, Planet Fitness, has attempted to coin the term "lunk" to describe people who go the gym excessively, and are disgustingly muscular, have a "bro" mentality, or have massive egos. Another thing that may help you understand, is that everyone who "grunts" while they exercise, matches the description of "lunk", everything else I said, is just what stereotypically describes the personality of someone who grunts while exercising. They are airing commercials on some major television networks (I've seen commercials on FX, CNN, Comedy Central, and more). Rather than feebly attempt to describe the exact meaning and connotation they're trying to convey, I'll just leave a link to their commercials that use/describe this word.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxsX4e6AF38

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn5mzEAMAkY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQfmpXsLV_4

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single word or shorter phrase that captures exactly the concept in your title, someone who goes to a gym frequently, with no other connotation, then **no, there is no single word that captures that concept**.

Certainly there are many words or phrases that do *include* as the primary meaning 'goes to a gym frequently', but they all add a little bit extra, all to the extent one can easily say "That person goes to the gym frequently but they are not an X' (fill in all the examples so far). For example,

> That person goes to the gym frequently, 5 times a week for cardio to help with their diabetes, but **they're not a gym rat**.

And there are many non-pejorative words for people who into fitness or sports where the gym is not a primary preoccupation. But there is nothing that captures exactly that idea.

In the end, to say that someone goes to a gym or fitness center regularly or frequently, you should say that

> they go to the gym frequently

That says everything you want and no more.

If you wanted some additional nuance, like they are a fitness fanatic, then please specify. Is it to augment their sports training? Is it for general health? Is it for the social aspect? Also, what connotations? Is it pejorative? Is it laudatory? Do you want a neologism or advertising slogan?

There are many concepts in our heads that don't necessarily have a single word to label them. That's why most languages allow multiple words to get closer to the nuance desired.

Comment: I suspected as much and if none existed, I also asked for a common or popular expression for that group of people or as many of the suggested answers imply, an individual or devotee. There seem to be quite a few, *gym-goer* is a neutral one, and *gym rat* another. Obviously, there is some need for such a word. Albeit the more derogatory terms seem to outnumber the positive ones, which for me, is quite interesting.

Answer (score -3):

Fitgit?

git: nounBRIT.informal -- 1. an unpleasant or contemptible person.

Comment: Not sure if that should be one word. I almost read it as "fidget". **:^)**

Comment: again why is a gym-goer unpleasant or contemptible?

Comment: Fitbit and *Git fit* exist but not *fitgit*.