# What do we call people who work out at home?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

This question was very interesting: [What do we call people who go to the gym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124665/what-do-we-call-people-who-go-to-the-gym)

Now I am wondering if there is a word for someone like me who works out *at home*. What I refer to is weight training, work with bars, HIIT (high intensive interval training) and some yoga or stretching exercises.

Comment: "home-trainer" ;)

Comment: I can't think of any established term, but "stay-at-home gym rat" (not unlike _stay-at-home mom_) could work, particularly if you have a lot of equipment at home. It also might depend on your motivation for staying at home: "shy fitness buff" might work, or "reclusive fitness buff," if your main reason for not going to the gym was that you didn't like to be around other people, or "broke fitness enthusiast" if your main reason was that you couldn't afford to become a member of a gym.

Comment: ‘Jane Fonda’? :-þ

Comment: Ha ha ha +J.R. it is because it is not time efficient - it takes you time to travel to gym and back, it takes time to go to get a locker or you have to speak with people, or suddenly you spend too much time using some machines because you have been distracted from women rears. Usually 150 lbs of weight and a bar do the same at home and here there aren't 24/7 gyms and I can't workout at 1 am in the morning for example. I do a simple program 6 exercise 3 sets of 10 repetition, watching about my form when doing it and doing it really slow, staying focus on the movement.

Comment: btw, not Jane Fonda but Scooby :) And women rears in running tights are a great pace maker when I am running on the track.

Comment: If you have home-schoolers, you can have home–work-outers. :)

Comment: Fat (Say they work out at home but don't really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such word. The closest would be "home training" or "home trainer" but I don't think it is extremely common and is likely to get confused with skill training at home or someone who comes to your home to train you in something.

Comment: Anything with 'trainer' and athletics screams British English.

Comment: @philshem: The most common usage in the US is "personal trainer" (although we also use "fitness instructor" or "physical therapist").

Comment: Yes, good point. But 'training' implies 'instructing', like for dogs.

Comment: @philshem: Not always. Athletics teams have entire segments of their calendars blocked off for "training" and most colleges offer "weight training" courses. (This is still US usage.)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard and used the expression, **closet gym rat**, to describe a person who works out a ton by themselves - usually at home.

Answer (score 0):

If someone works out where they live, they'd be called a domestic trainer