# A person who goes to gymnastics school -- a 'student' or a 'pupil?'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, ambiguity

I am trying to find an exact answer of this question:

Is a person who goes to gymnastics school a 'student' or a 'pupil?'

Comment: It's a valid question, I hadn't realized that it might be possible for a learner to confuse gym with gymnasium (the humanities school) and gymnastics. But the ambiguity disappears when a context is given.

Comment: If the marketing department had its way, they would be called customers or clients...

Comment: The title should be changed as a "Gymnastics school" - if such a thing existed - could only be where pupils studied gymnastics.

Comment: @TheMathemagician and what would you suggest the OP change the title to? The question stemmed from his suggestion that a person who frequents a gym be called a pupil. He was informed by a user that a pupil was the same as a student, i.e. a person who goes to school and I had urged him to look up the word, gym, in a dictionary. Obviously, the OP looked up *gym* read it was short for *gymnasium* which is indeed a type of school, but, for whatever reason, he transcribed it as *gymnastics school* (phew!). Unfortunately his answer has been deleted but if you have 10,000+ rep you can still read it.

Comment: Mari, Do you have any other nearest word except your given answer?

Comment: Hi! Mari, your answer will be highly appreciated to me.

Comment: Actually, at this point I am curious if someone does provide an answer for an attendee of a gymnastics *school*. If you study a discipline, be it sport, science or art, I suppose you could be called a student (but not a pupil).

Comment: Thank you very much. you taught me. what will you wish to take?

Comment: I would love to edit this question into shape, but despite reading every word the OP has written, I still haven't the faintest clue whether he's actually wondering about "gymnastics school", i.e. a school where kids are taught tumbling, parallel bar, vault, balance beam, and the like; or whether he's actually trying to ask a duplicate of the "what do you call gym goers" question; or whether he's wondering about gymnasiums (gymnasia?), i.e. the rough equivalent of American "high school"; or something else entirely.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I believe OP is asking about a gymnasium meaning a fairly academic school. A good equivalent in British English would be a grammar school. Unfortunately many native English speakers are unaware that gymnasium has any meaning other than the one they know so the answers are ridiculously irrelevant.

Comment: When I was at school (in the UK in the 60's and 70's) somebody who went to a school was called a pupil. The type of school was irrelevant (and _school_ does not include college or university in the UK). A _student_ was somebody who attendeda higher institution: a college or university. Some time in the 80's I started encountering _student_ used for schoolchildren and found it strange - I thought of it as an American usage.

Comment: What about apprentice? Disciple? Learner? I think *apprentice* applies here since a person learning gymnastics in a gym from gymnasts would be an apprentice, wouldn't it?

Comment: Always check a dictionary before asking on ELU.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATED (We need pictures)

### Schools of Gymnastics

[image]

*Gymnastics schools* exist, but the more common term is *Schools of gymnastics*. In the US there is the *Los Angeles School of Gymnastics* and
on their website, the children who attend these classes are simply called: girls, boys, child or children (trust me I went through a lot of pages).

> ([Boys: beginner classes](http://www.lagymnastics.com/classes/boys-gymnastics/boys-beginning/)) Our classes emphasize proper training techniques of the bars, beam,
>   vault, floor exercise, flexibility training, strength training and
>   more! Each class is carefully constructed to motivate your **child** in a fun and progressive environment... ([Boys: intermediate classes](http://www.lagymnastics.com/classes/boys-gymnastics/boys-intermediate/)) **Boys** intermediate classes become a bit longer to help with the increased skill level required to learn intermediate level gymnastics. ([Girls team](http://www.lagymnastics.com/classes/girls-gymnastics/girls-intermediate/girls-team/)) The award winning pre-team programs are designed to prepare **athletes** for the competitive arena of USA Gymnastics (governing body of gymnastics the United States).

However, there was one page where the term, *students*, was used

> The Los Angeles School of Gymnastics offers financial aid/[scholarship](http://www.lagymnastics.com/programs/scholarship/)
>   to **students** after a six month enrolment period. After the 6 month
>   commitment, the **student** will need to bring in the most recent tax
>   return from the family household.

**The Wiltshire School of Gymnastics** in the UK is undoubtedly a smaller school with humbler ambitions but nevertheless with a history dating back to 1975. Again the school prefers to identify their members as children, girls, boys or gymnasts.

> [WSG](http://www.wiltshireschoolofgymnastics.co.uk/about-us/4544437823) were honoured to welcome the Princess Royal, Princess Anne, on
>   Thursday 8th February 2001, to perform the official opening. Seating
>   was provided for parents and **the gymnasts** undertook a normal training
>   session with one or two displays intermingled. (...) Princess Anne also met and talked to the **gymnasts** alongside whichever piece of apparatus they happened to be training on as she passed by on her tour of the facilities.

Another American school called **International Gymnastics Camp** uses the term, gymnast extensively. If you have the inclination, watch the video on their [World Class facilities](http://www.internationalgymnastics.com/facilities/index.php) page. The size of their gyms, the sheer number of apparatus available, the level of professionalism is in a word, astounding. In the video, the children are always referred to as *"kids"* never students.

> IGC campers range in age from 7 to 17 and are from beginner to
>   advanced **gymnasts**. (...) Our reputation as an innovator and our constantly evolving facility bring **gymnasts** here from around the world. (...) Each summer over 4000 **aspiring gymnasts** ranging from beginners to Olympians attend this one of a kind facility. (...) Instructors set individual goals with their campers and teach new gymnastics skills with each individual **gymnast**, in addition to improving **gymnast’s** technique in current skills.

---

### Gymnasium

<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnasium_%28school%29)</sup>

> is a type of school with a strong emphasis on academic learning, and
>   providing advanced secondary education in some parts of Europe and the
>   CIS, comparable to British grammar schools, sixth form colleges and
>   U.S. preparatory high schools. **In its current meaning, it usually
>   refers to secondary schools focused on preparing students to enter a
>   university for advanced academic study.**

[image]

In Italy we have *[Il liceo Classico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liceo_classico)*, students will study the humanities, Latin, ancient Greek, two foreign languages and in some lyceums, a musical instrument is also "studied". In the UK/England there is no such type of school, the nearest equivalent would be a [grammar school](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_school) but between the 70s and 80s many were transformed into comprehensive state schools.

In the all the above cases, yes, a young person who attends any of these scholastic institutions is normally called **a student**. The word *pupil* nowadays is perhaps considered old fashioned and better suited for nursery schools (kindergarten in the US) and primary schools.

### Gym

<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gym)</sup>

> is slang for gymnasium and gymnastic services such as in schools and
>   colleges and is attributed to compounds such as gym shoes. Gymnasia
>   are **open air and covered locations for gymnastics and athletics**.

### Gymnasium

<sup>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gymnasium?show=0&t=1397886406)</sup>

> 1 a :  **a large room used for various indoor sports** (as basketball or
>   boxing) **and usually equipped with gymnastic apparatus** b :  a building
>   (as on a college campus) containing space and equipment for various
>   indoor sports activities and usually including spectator
>   accommodations, locker and shower rooms, offices, classrooms, and a
>   swimming pool

[image]

People (i.e. the general public) who regularly attend gyms are NOT called gymnasts, students, or pupils. I would call them *gym goers* or *gym rats*. See this question [What do we call people who go to the gym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124665/what-do-we-call-people-who-go-to-the-gym)

### Gymnastics Schools

<sup>[What is gymnastics](http://www.british-gymnastics.org/gymnasts/getting-started/what-is-gymnastics)</sup>

These are schools which train (or teach) children and adults *gymnastics*, a complex discipline that includes different agility and coordination exercises all of which require years of practice and dedication. Girls/women will usually do exercises on uneven bars, balance beam, floor, vaulting horse and floor exercise; while boys/men will specialize on the horizontal and parallel bars, rings, floor, pommel horse and floor exercise. People who take up this sport seriously and compete in competitions are usually called **gymnasts**.

Comment: Check this out, Mari-Lou http://www.nj.com/news/index.ssf/2014/02/south_jersey_teacher_may_lose_job_after_two_kindergarten_students_admitted_to_having_sex_in_bathroom.html. http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ymyp7HN2X34C&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22nursery+school+students%22&source=bl&ots=QUfW8DDCDx&sig=TxhsCb-2EcxeGDnJwRn6KSxy-Fw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=LylSU4XCNIS6OPuDgXg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22nursery%20school%20students%22&f=false. Nursery school and kindergarten children are also referred to as "students" in the US.

Comment: Mostly interchangeable? Check out this NGram, ML https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten+students%2Ckindergarten+pupils%2Cnursery+school+students%2Cnursery+school+pupils&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20pupils%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20school%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20school%20pupils%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @NourishedGourmet  The graph proves that the expression "students" is gaining popularity. Again, at the risk of repeating myself, *pupils* is considered old-fashioned nowadays. Thank you for confirming my earlier statement.

Comment: But "Nursery children" wins hands down! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten+students%2Ckindergarten+pupils%2Cnursery+children%2Cnursery+pupils&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20pupils%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20pupils%3B%2Cc0

Comment: AFA BrE is concerned, it does. ;-) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten+students%2Ckindergarten+pupils%2Cnursery+children%2Cnursery+pupils&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%20pupils%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20children%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Also, studere comes from latin and simply means "to put effort in smth". So yeah, that applies to sport as well.

Comment: There is a subtlety that **pupils** tends to be used when there is an association with a particular school: "The pupils of St. Cuthbert's ... " However I agree that **students** is becoming more used for all cases whereas formerly it was more for university level, or at least 16+. Without any context **students** would still be taken to mean 18+ year olds in tertiary education. (I'm referring to British English.)

Comment: There is a lot of extra info in this post that really doesn't have anything to do with the question Mari-Lou.  Some might not be entirely accurate, especially from a AE point of view.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd   Agreed about the extra info, but I posted this answer BEFORE the bounty. I was trying to help the OP understand why suggesting *pupil* for a person who goes to the gym was wrong(see comments under OP's question). He's evidently not happy about the answer, so he posts the bounty. I haven't seen any valid alternative answers in 6 days, so that bounty is mine! :) As for AmEng inaccuracies, where are they? Would you mind sharing? I included two American schools for gymnasts, so I hope it's nothing to do with them.

Comment: We workout at a gym.  Kids play basketball in their school gym.  Gymnastics training is at a gym (can be called other things).  Gym just can be used for almost anything in the US that is indoors and involves working out or sports.  We are a lazy bunch with our naming convention.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd yes, but the sport is gymnastics, not gym. And the wikipedia article, says gym is short for gymnasium, which it is. And my bet is that the OP looked up gymnasium, and rightly thought to himself, pupils or students attend gymnasiums (schools which teach the humanities). Anyway, good luck with the bounty!

Comment: I am assuming that the OP's question is written in correct English.  If you are guessing that it isn't and answering it based on that then the question should be closed.  Your answer is for a different question than the one presented.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I have provided, in my opinion, a non-equivocal and complete answer.

Comment: Mari-Lou - you do a very good job at policing some of the drudge that the site gets.  Often you comment on something I misread.  Your first set of answers had nothing to do with "gymnastics".  Yet it was upvoted 3-4 times.  Meaning that the people voting don't understand English well.  Then you changed your answer after I posted something that tried to answer the question.   But you kept your new answer as part of your old (non)answer.  Just saying that you lose some credibility in setting policy if you don't follow the same SE rules.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I included "gynastics school" in my original answer. the fact the OP set up a bounty frankly confuses me, so I must presume  he didn't understand. There's no SE law prohibiting me from editing an answer of mine, if I see fit. Moreover, I haven't copied anyone's  suggestions. I said from the beginning that children who attend gymnastic classes are NOT called students or pupils, I suggested *gymnast*. I later checked with several sources online and posted my "updated" answer. I HAVE NOT CHANGED MY ANSWER, I've improved on it. Check the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon their age and level of agency.  In general, a student may or may not have chosen to study, but a pupil has made no choice.  So we can have Elementary School Students or Pupils, but College Students never College Pupils.

Answer (score 1):

> **[pupil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pupil)** *n*. (Random House Kernerman Webster's Col. Dict.)
>   a person, usu. **young**, who is learning under the supervision of a teacher at school or a private tutor; student.
> [1350–1400; *pupille* < Middle French < Latin pūpillus (masculine), *pūpilla* (feminine) orphan, ward, diminutives of *pūpus* boy, *pūpa* girl]

[emphasis added]

In the context of education, *pupil* is generally used for children (law: below 14/12), while *student* is used for the adolescents/ adults. However, *student* is broader, while *pupil* is not.

Whether a "school" teaches gymnastics or another subject, probably does not tell us anything about whether those attending it are *pupils* or *students*. Rather, it is their age that matters.

Comment: The link to "ward", I think, indicates this is really about the degree of agency, rather than directly about age.  Study requires a choice, whereas being force-fed information makes you a pupil.

Answer (score 1):

One early gymnastics school in the United States (during an era known as the [Battle of the Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Systems)) was the Posse Normal School of Gymnastics, which opened in 1890 in Boston and taught "Swedish gymnastics." As [this classified ad](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2249&dat=19131018&id=_BonAAAAIBAJ&sjid=cgMGAAAAIBAJ&pg=2369,3684582) from the *Boston Evening Transcript* (October 18, 1913) indicates the school called its attendees "students":

> POSSE NORMAL SCHOOL OF GYMNASTICS
>
> 777–781 BEACON STREET
>
> Now open. New building with latest modern improvements. Classes forming. Opportunity for every kind of gymnastic and athletic work. Normal **students** in educational and medical gymnastics received until Nov. 1st. Hall to let for clubs, dancing parties, etc. Office hours 9 to 5. Evenings by appointment.

On the other hand, Dr. E. H. Arnold, "[Discussion](http://books.google.com/books?id=2TgXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA890&dq=%22gymnastics+school%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NZZeU4OgIo6wyASxioK4CQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22gymnastics%20school%22&f=false)," in response to Professor Carl Kroh, "The German System of Gymnastics," in National Educational Association, *Journal of Proceedings and Addresses of the Thirty-Sixth Annual Meeting* held at Milwaukee, Wisconsin (July 6–9, 1897), writes as follows:

> As the number of modifying positions, free standing, is limited, the use of gymnastic apparatus which allows the reproduction of the same type of movement in sheer endless variety, presenting it in all stages of difficulty, is of utmost importance and greatest help. The teacher is, however, not the only person benefited by such help, but the **pupil** is quick to learn by analogy what feature of the exercise decides its greatest or less difficulty.

It thus appears that discussions of gymnastics schools (or at least of gymnastics taught in schools) have historically used both *student* and *pupil* to refer to the person being taught, coached, or trained in gymnastics.Both terms continue to be used in contemporary times. From [*Bottom Line Business*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cw8cAQAAMAAJ&q=%22gymnastics+school%22&dq=%22gymnastics+school%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BJ5eU_nhENKHyATfk4KIDw&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBDgU), volume 29 (2000) [snippet]:

> ***Example:*** A gymnastics school in Texas sends a thank-you letter to parents of **students**. The letter asks for referrals and gives a discount to current customers if at least two referrals sign up.

From Brad Herzog, [*20 Greatest Athletes of the 20th Century*](http://books.google.com/books?ei=b5xeU_iiBMiryASMxoCgDA&id=n8E03gNpH0YC&dq=%22gymnastics+school%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22pupil%22) (2000) [snippet]:

> Bela [Karolyi] would later coach U.S. champions Mary Lou Retton and Kim Zmeskal, but Nadia [Comăneci] was his first famous **pupil**. Have you ever heard the expression, Practice makes perfect? Well, if that is true, Nadia was on her way!

From a cursory look at search results for recent occurrences of "gymnastics school" in Google Books, however, it appears that writers use *student* more frequently than *pupil* to describe the people taking these classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, absolutely so.
Though you could call him a gymnast but pupil is good.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it depends on the identity of the person. That's mean we should know what's the relationship between you and that person.

Answer (score -1):

First I am assuming that you are talking about a place that teaches gymnastics like the picture below.

[image]

In AE a gymnastic schools normally aren't called schools.  They would be called centres (centers), academy, or clubs.  Some may still be called schools but that is older terminology.  They would usually have the word training in them too.  So an average name might be New York Gymnastic Training Academy.

If you belong to a gymnastic "school" you could go by student but that is so 90s.  Now you would probably go by **athlete**, **aspiring athlete**, or more likely **team member**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't really care about the bounty.  I didn't answer it originally because I thought it should be on ELL.  It is common sense to me - that is if the question is even written correctly, which your original answer might be right.  I just think the regulars need to take a small stand on answering questions when they aren't written in correct English.  Or we will keep getting these.  The site has become much more like ELL over the past couple months... and we keep answering the questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I see more and more people writing answers for what they think the OP might be asking.  Maybe this would be a good meta topic.  In my opinion if it isn't clear, if the OP can't write in correct English, or if they can't use basic grammar I think it gets closed or moved.  I understand your original answer, I just think it is a slippery slope to give it.  The fact that you gave it is just trying to help the OP but the fact that people upvoted an answer when you clearly stated you weren't sure what was being asked is worse... in my opinion.

Comment: Ahh, but you see the question is very clear, and grammatically acceptable, it's not a duplicate and it's not off-topic. I've seen worse questions posted and be upvoted. In the end I was intrigued and realized that the word, gym, whose meaning seemed so obvious to me could be easily misinterpreted by a non native speaker. I don't think speakers of European languages will be confused (In Italy we have *ginnasio*, *palestra* and *il keep fit*) but what of other speakers? The OP's question is not dumb, it's a valid one. Take a look at the original question, before the edit, it was very clear.

Comment: But it certainly could be closed duplicate for anything that has students vs pupil or be closed because of common knowledge.  Either the question is too basic or not written how they wanted it written.

Comment: Put yourself in the non-native speaker's shoes. You look up the word "gym" in the dictionary. The second definition tells you  *a European secondary school that prepares students for the university*. You see it is short for gymnasium, you look up the word, find it is a school, but in your mind you confuse it with gymnastics (a word you are more familiar with because of TV, The Olympics etc..) and the rest is history. It's a misunderstanding, and as such, I think it's worthy pointing that out.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - so we are non-native English detectives?  I totally understand where you are coming from but I think it will cause more poor questions on the site if they are given attention.  It is an easy ELL question.