# What can be the full synonym for "fitness enthusiast"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What could be a single word to "fitness enthusiast" ?

Comment: You can use fitness nut, but it's still two words.

Comment: If the person is spending too much time in gyms, you may call them "gym rats"

Comment: Similar previous question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124665/what-do-we-call-people-who-go-to-the-gym  Gymaholic was suggested in that discussion, so perhaps 'fitness-holic' works here. Not very snappy though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type of fitness it is use that word and `-er`. For example:

- runner (running enthusiast)
- hiker (hiking enthusiast)
- swimmer (swimming enthusiast)

Answer (score 0):

**exerciser**

According to Google, it means:

> a person who exercises.

According to Dictionary.com, it means:

> a person or thing that exercises

According to TheFreeDictionary.com, it means:

> One that exercises

Comment: *I* exercise, I'm not remotely enthusiastic about it.